# UIViewControllerRepresentable instantiates view controllers over and over

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I'm new to development on iOS. So, I made a ViewController with Storyboard and am showing it in SwiftUI View on a button click.
Representable:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

struct StartTraining: UIViewControllerRepresentable{
 
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<StartTraining>) -> UIViewController {
        
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
       let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "StartTraining")
    
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<StartTraining>) {
      //I'm not updating anything, I just need to show the ViewController and everything will be done there
    }
 

   
}
```

SwiftUI View:

```
struct WorkoutDescriptionView: View {
    @State private var isPresented = false

  var body: some View {
    
                Button(action: {
                    self.isPresented = true
                    
                }, label: {
                    Text("Start")
                        .bold()
                        .font(.title2)
                        .frame(width: 350, height: 50)
                        .background(Color.green)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                })
                    .padding(.bottom).fullScreenCover(isPresented:$isPresented){
                        StartTraining().ignoresSafeArea()
                        
                       
                    }
                }
```

And it works! I do see the ViewController in full screen when I click the button, however, there is really a lot going on in the ViewController, and memory usage increases by 200 MB once I click the Start Button in WorkoutDescriptionView, and when I want to go back to the Main Menu (ContentView()) written in SwiftUI on a button click inside the ViewController, only 20MB of the memory usage gets released, and you can see where this is going: with every consecutive button click to open ViewController memory usage increases by 200MB or even more without being released. (So it is like: 300MB of total memory usage on the first button click, then 500MB on the second click, then 700, and so on)

Inside View Controller there is a button that shows another ViewController:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
              
let secondVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ResultStoryboard")
            self.show(secondVC, sender: self)
```

And from the other ViewController I return to the Main Menu:

```
 @objc func didTapButton(){
        
ViewController.updateFirebaseValues()
        ViewController.camera.stop()
       
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            
            let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
           
            present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
 //           self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
           
            
            
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
       
      
        
    }
```

I think I manage to kill all operations inside the heavy and loaded ViewController because I see only black screen if I dismiss transition to ContentView(), so I think the issue is in my constantly instantiating new view controllers from storyboard and presenting them on Button click without removing previously created ones.
Here:

```
   func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<StartTraining>) -> UIViewController {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
       let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "StartTraining")

        return controller
    }
```

So my question is: what is the best practice to open uikit view controllers from switui view and release all the memory when closing view controller while coming back to SwiftUI view?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Not sure if I get your question clearly, if you are trying to go back to the main menu, essentially dismissing all the presented view controllers then let I'll ask  if your SwiftUI app based on UIAppDelegate or it's pure SwiftUI

Comment: @Jolly yes, I'm trying to go to the main menu, closing absolutely all the view controllers while doing that. The project is UIAppDelegate based, Main menu is ContentView, so it is written in SwiftUI... I am mixing frameworks, going from SwiftUI to UIKit and vice versa, I wish I didn't have to do that, but some of the features I'm using are only available in UIKit.

Comment: @vm_1_r what features? Even if you do have to use UIKit, I wouldn't recommend using storyboards. They may allow for quick prototyping but they're opaque, hard to understand, and a hand wave over the important stuff that's going on. It's hard to say what's going on because storyboards are kind of a black box.

Comment: @barndog not exactly features of uikit. As I said I'm novice in iOS development, and come from Java, so I looked at Storyboards and thought they were kinda easier to understand as an android dev where we can work very easily with layouts, so I started to work in UIKit. I integrated frameworks that use camera output for pose estimation and calculations and I couldn't transfer same logic to SwiftUI, so at the end I decided to stick with UIKit, and it is great, everything works, I just can't figure out how to prevent reinstantiating view controller over and over in StartTraining struct

Answer (score 0):

try

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

if it's embedded in a UINavigationController do

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

this code goes in the view controller you are dismissing from so in your case:

```
@objc func didTapButton(){
        
ViewController.updateFirebaseValues()
        ViewController.camera.stop()
   
       UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) // adjustment is here
     
        
    }
```